# tikz bug in curve to from nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

This may be well-known, but I cannot remember having encountered this before. Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{vert/.style={circle,inner sep=1mm,draw}}
\tikzset{edge/.style={draw=#1,very thick}}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.5]
\node[vert] (a) at (1.,1.3){};
\node[vert] (b) at (1.7,1.3){};
\draw[edge=blue,out=0,in=225] (a) to (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.5,rotate=225]
\node[vert] (a) at (1.,1.3){};
\node[vert] (b) at (1.7,1.3){};
\draw[edge=blue,out=0,in=225] (a) to (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

In the rotated picture, the line is not attached correctly to the nodes:

[image]

Is that really a bug, or am I missing something? any known fix?

Comment: It's definitely not new, I can reproduce this behaviour with PGF as old as 3.0.0 (TeX Live 2015).

Comment: If you add `transform shape` to the picture you get the correct curve but of course also a scaling of the nodes.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it is a bug or not, but the behaviour should definitely be more predictable. I opened a new issue for that: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/730

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I agree with Shady Puck that this is not a bug. However, an arguably more precise way of explaining what's going on is to recall that by default nodes do not get transformed. If you want to transform them, i.e. subject the node anchors to the transformations, you need to say `transform shape`. (In your setting, one needs to undo the scale transformation to match the presumably desired result.)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{vert/.style={circle,inner sep=1mm,draw}}
\tikzset{edge/.style={draw=#1,very thick}}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.5]
\node[vert] (a) at (1.,1.3){};
\node[vert] (b) at (1.7,1.3){};
\draw[edge=blue,out=0,in=225] (a) to (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.5,rotate=225,transform shape]
\node[vert,scale=1/2.5] (a) at (1.,1.3){};
\node[vert,scale=1/2.5] (b) at (1.7,1.3){};
\draw[edge=blue,out=0,in=225] (a) to (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice explanation. Are you really a cat (assuming it is possible to know)?

Comment: @frougon Nothing is certain in our (quantum) world.

Answer (score 6):

It's not a bug -- the behavior is easily fixed.

When you specify a modifier for the whole picture, what Ti*k*Z does is apply this modifier to the picture **and** each object individually. Therefore, it is necessary to offset this individual rotation from the general with our own proportional individualized rotations. After fiddling with the signs for a hot second, I got this code to produce this result.

```
\tikzset{vert/.style={circle,inner sep=1mm,draw}}
\tikzset{edge/.style={draw=#1,very thick}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.5]
    \node[vert] (a) at (1.,1.3){};
    \node[vert] (b) at (1.7,1.3){};
    \draw[edge=blue,out=0,in=225] (a) to (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.5,rotate=225]
    \node[vert,rotate=-225] (a) at (1.,1.3){};
    \node[vert,rotate=225] (b) at (1.7,1.3){};
    \draw[edge=blue,out=0,in=225] (a) to (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: You have to rotate both nodes by `225`.  The minus sign for `(a)` is wrong.

Comment: @HenriMenke Just turn the second node 225, the first node turns without any problem. `\node[vert] (a) at (1.,1.3){};\node[vert,rotate=225] (b) at (1.7,1.3){};`